# Applying a css filter only to the text inside input box?

Tags: css

I mean only to the text typed in by the user. When trying to use drop-shadow, for example, this happens: [image: no desc]

Edit:

```
filter: drop-shadow(10px 5px 0 #16a861);
```

https://codepen.io/krozshardt/pen/bGVaVVP

I am sorry I was unclear when I have first asked my question. I find it difficult to explain my purpose, yet I will give it a try. 
As seen in the screenshot and codepen, the css filter property is applied to the input box rather than the text itself. It would work in this case using text-shadow, but there's no such solution for every filter, like a hue-rotate, for example.

Comment: Could you please add your code?

Comment: Edited adding the code and an apology for being unclear.

Comment: Can you set my answer to the accepted answer, since it worked for your initial question. It would help others find answered questions quicker. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a text shadow with the CSS property:

**Example:**

```
.input-classname {
    text-shadow: 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

Source:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp

**Edit**

I would also advice to use older techniques that have better support in different browsers, if that is possible of course. The filter property is also quite 'new' (for browser land) and doesn't work in all browser versions or can have it's quirks. For support and more in depth information I would recommend [MDN (a very good source for your code)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) and [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/)

Also browsers limit your styling options a little for form field (buttons, inputs etc.). You have to reset these OR you have to resort to other changes.

Comment: It worked for my specific example, but there's no workaround for every css filter, like mentioned in the edit.

Comment: Indeed, for your specific request/question this works. Filters are quite 'new' and are a functionality on their own, with their own new unique properties. So trying to achieve the same through other 'older' techniques might be difficult or impossible to replicate.
Also I would recommend using a site like caniuse.com to check the browser support since filters are not widely supported yet. Of course this depends on the scope of the project and most importantly your users that visit your site, but that's a completely different topic. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are trying to apply to the text. If you are trying to change the `font-family` in the text input, then this should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
    <style>

        body {
            font-family: Verdana
        }

        .input {
            font-family: cursive;
        }

    </style>
<body>

    <form action="javascript:void(0)" class="form-container">

            <input type="text" class="input"></input>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Notice the CSS is applying the filter to the input itself, but it changed the text. If you are trying to apply a different filter to the text, but can't do it by applying the filter to the input, then there may be a slight change to the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
    <style>

        body {
            font-family: Verdana
        }

        .inputText {
            filter: drop-shadow(8px 8px 10px gray);
        }

    </style>
<body>

    <form action="javascript:void(0)" class="form-container">

            <input type="text"><span class="inputText"></span></input>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice in the code above I gave the text a class by adding `<span>` elements around it. I really hope this works, as it might not. An 8-year-old might make a mistake here and there... :)